# Regular expression for matching git branch prefixes in specified order

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a git hook that will not allow user to push his commit into the branch that do not follow our branches prefixes rules.

So, for matching the branch name I need to write a regular expression.
Here is the example list representing ordering of the branch prefixes:

- **ex** - experimental
- **d** - devops
- **b** - back-end
- **f** - front-end

So, for instance we have the following branch names that should match:

Branch name may have additional words after prefixes as below (e.g -git-hooks, -api).

Each branch name have to contain at least one prefix (e.g **-ex**).

1. **`<developer>-ex-d`** - developer's experimental branch with devops implementation of a git hooks
2. **`ex-b-f`** - experimental branches with back-end and front-end api implementation

Branches names that shouldn't match:

1. **`<developer>-d-ex-f-b`** - illegal prefixes order
2. **`exp-front-back`** - illegal prefixes

The most difficult part for me is too understand how to match prefixes in correct order without their repetition.

Thanks in advance for answering!

Comment: Are the branch prefixes always adjacent?

Comment: how do you know if a word is an illegal prefix instead of the branch name?

Comment: Agree with @Nathan ... the illegal prefix requirement is going to be hard to handle.

Comment: Thanks for answering! The branch name may contain any prefix from the list, but they need to be in concrete order. I will edit my post to add more clarification.

Comment: @Nathan A word after prefixes list is always at the end of the branch name. I think that it is possible to find last legal prefix and after just strip it or so. The whole idea is in matching list of prefixes in the correct order.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes.

Comment: but how do I know that for instance exp (in the last example) is a prefix instead of a word? Do you have the branch name?

Comment: This isn't a task for regex. There are too many combinations of prefixes. Which programming language are you using?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I think I am now agree with you. I am using shell for writing a git hook. I will try to write some shell magic that will handle it for me.

Comment: @Nathan Sorry for late response. Firstly I thought that if we have predefined set of prefixes, we can try to match prefix and dash(-) after each prefix.

Comment: @Nathan, For example, branch name can be **kyrylo-ex-b-f**.

Answer (score 1):

Either I haven't understood you correctly, or this is what you want

```
/^([^-]+)?(-ex)?(-d)?(-b)?(-f)?(?!((-ex)|(-d)|(-b)|(-f)))(-.*)?$/
```

See https://regexr.com/3l4t4 to see it working

This looks for your prefixes in sequence, then uses a negative lookahead to enforce no duplicates, then allows other name chunks subsequently.

Actually, there's a bug: this will disallow (eg) `<developer>-ex-d-dev` because it thinks there's a duplicate `-d`. I'll leave the answer here in case someone else can improve it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try to fix a bug now!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to answer this with regex, but in python it can be done like this (I know it's not a pretty answer but it works):

```
import re


def check_prefixes(string_to_check):
    lst_prefixes = ['-ex-', '-d-', '-b-', '-f-']
    # find position of all prefixes (-1 indicates prefix was not present and so can be skipped)
    lst_positions = [string_to_check.find(prefix) for prefix in lst_prefixes if string.find(prefix) != -1]

    string_correct = True
    # if the prefixes aren't in the right order the string isn't correct
    if sorted(lst_positions) != lst_positions:
        string_correct = False
    else:
        # find all the prefixes
        # the string needs to be adjusted so that re.findall actually finds all the prefixes and doesn't skip the even numbered ones or the first/last
        string_to_check= '-' + string_to_check.split('>-')[-1].replace('-', '--') + '-'
        all_prefixes = re.findall('(-.*?-)', string_to_check)

        # check if all the prefixes are legal
        for prefix in all_prefixes:
            if prefix not in lst_prefixes: 
                string_correct = False
                break

    return string_correct


to_check = ['<developer>-ex-d',
            'ex-b-f',
            '<developer>-d-ex-f-b',
            'exp-front-back']

for string_to_check in to_check:
    print '{} = {}'.format(string_to_check, check_prefixes(string_to_check))
```

Perhaps you can make it work in whatever coding language you're most comfortable in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I will think about rewriting my bash script (git hook) into Python. Maybe this will be a good idea. The most aim is in working with full shell functionality due to python subprocess shell-outing (which is painful).

Answer (score 0):

To do with a single regex it may be easier to match the unwanted branches :

- without suffix `^[-]*$`
- other than `ex`,`d`,`b`,`f` : `-(?!(ex|d|b|f)(-|$))[^-]*`
- not followed by one of expected suffixes 
  `-ex-(?!(d|b|f)(-|$))|
  -d-(?!(b|f)(-|$))|
  -b-(?!f(-|$))`

[can be checked on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/17Gl3H/1)